# Button click event is not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

When I click the button it does not fire an event and does not display any JavaScript message.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmitQues" runat="server" 
            CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnSubmitQues_Click" 
            Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="other" 
            OnClientClick="if(!confirm('Please Make sure to attach correct File and Select correct options !!')) return false;"/>
```

Comment: plz show code for aspx

Comment: where are those codes?

Comment: Give code for what you have tried, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Please give more information. You have not made an effort to explain or show your code.

Comment: Check for my answer, there is no need of if condition when confirm already returns bool value.

Answer (score 4):

Use confirm like below for button.

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Please Make sure to attach correct File and Select correct options !!');"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`OnClick` is server side, for javascript use `onClientClick`

Comment: OnClientClick="if(!confirm('Please Make sure to attach correct File and Select correct options !!')) return false;" i using

Answer (score 0):

in order to excute serverside button click any time, you will have to remove  `return false` from javascript.

You will have to call javascript function through `onClientclick=funname()`

and server side .cs page function through `onclick=function name();`

When javascript function returns `false`, it does not executes your server side code.

When true is returned by javascript function then postback occures and it executes onclick method.

From your code (which you shown previously) it seems you have used only onclick parameter

Below can be your code for button

```
<asp:button id="Button1"
       usesubmitbehavior="true"
       text="Open Web site"
       onclientclick="Navigate()"
       runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: OnClientClick="if(!confirm('Please Make sure to attach correct File and Select correct options !!')) return false;" this is my code

Answer (score 0):

I just tried you code in an `aspx` page and it is working perfectly.
When I press `OK` in *Confirm box*, it fires the *Button Click Event* at *Server side*, otherwise just stays on the page.

So, something else is preventing this to be clickable.

I guess the `ValidationGroup="other"` preventing it from being validated and thus it is not firing the `OnClientClick` event.